# somethig wrong with the view function in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, view

```
public function urls($id = null) {
    $this->Movie->id = $id;
    $this->set('Movie' , $this->Movie->read(null, $id));
    if ($this->request->is('requested')) {
        return $this->set('Movie' , $this->Movie->read(null, $id));
    }
    if (!$this->Movie->exists()){
    $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'pages','action' => 'display'));
    }
```

}

this is my view function, but it doesn't work !, when the page load, do a predictor to

```
$this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
```

i don't know what is the problem, but all other public functions in the movie app working good, please help !

PS: i have the same problem with delete function in users app

```
public function delete($id = null) {
    if (!$this->request->is('post')) {
        throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
    }
    $this->User->id = $id;
    if (!$this->User->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('المستخدم مش صالح'));
    }
    if ($this->User->delete()) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('تم يا تيت'));
        $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'pages','action' => 'display'));
    }
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('الحمد لله , مترمتش , حاول تاني'));
    $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'pages','action' => 'display'));
}
```

Comment: Please describe _what_ doesn't work

Comment: everything is good now, thanks @BenGraham

Comment: some more details would help?

Comment: everything is good now, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model is "Movie", not "movie".

Look here:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html

Comment: i user movie in 12 public function and working good, but this the only function doesn't want to work !!! when i use Movie give error with read()

Comment: But it is not correct, you have to follow CakePHP conventions.
For the rest, you have to report other errors.

Comment: Besides, you're wrong method. "Read" also sets the model:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-read

Try this at the third line:

 $this->set('movie' , $this->Movie->read(null, $id));

Comment: i have changed everything to  Movie, and other functions working good, but the urls function didn't work yet

Answer (score 1):

Here I found one mistake.

```
$this->movie->exists();
```

is not a correct syntax use `$this->Movie->exists()` 
instead of 'movie' you can use "Movie"

hope this helps

Comment: may i know what you are trying to do

Comment: just a page to read and view the movies article "title, subject..."

Comment: can you tell me  what problem it is giving? sorry for asking but it is working fine for me

Comment: when i go to /movies/view/10 , do director to movies/index/, when i remove the redirect from the view() function, open the movies/view/10 but give me no result

Comment: since there is no record with id 10 and i think you want to access it